# Wordpress - Cannot get terms of product categories with construct function use WC_Widget

Tags: wordpress

I used Woocommerce and want to create a widget that select product categories of product post type. My widget extends WC_Widget. But when I use the function get_terms('product_cat') in __construct() then an error:

```
object(WP_Error)#1330 (2) { ["errors":"WP_Error":private]=> array(1) { ["invalid_taxonomy"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(16) "Invalid taxonomy" } } ["error_data":"WP_Error":private]=> array(0) { } }
```

My Code:

```
register_widget('productCarousel');

class productCarousel extends WC_Widget{
    function __construct(){
        $this->widget_cssclass = 'kp-latest-product-widget';
        $this->widget_id = 'kopa-product-carousel';
        $this->widget_name = 'Kopa Product Carousel';
        $this->widget_description = 'A product carousel widget';
        $cats = get_terms('product_cat');
        parent::__construct();
    }
```

Please help me get product information! :(

Answer (score 1):

That's because the taxonomy tree has not been initiated before your call.

Please take a look at [the wordpress.org discussion](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/get_categories-with-taxonomy-not-working-in-functionphp)
and [another similiar question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73431/using-get-terms-for-custom-taxonomy-in-functions-php).

Some folks had fixed with adding a new function to functions.php like

```
function retrieve_my_terms() {

    global $terms;

    $terms = get_terms('taxonomy');

    foreach ($terms as $term) {
       $option = $term->name;
         return $option;
    }
 }
```

and you should give priority to your function for init

```
add_action('init', 'retrieve_my_terms', 9999);
```

edit:

My solution is a little bit different but gives me the form i want.

You can edit panel options and include some html elements on form creation function. On that time, all taxonomy tree and query options had been prepared. So, you can get whatever data you want.

```
public function form( $instance ){

    $allProductCategories = get_terms('product_cat');
    $this->settings["catSelection"]  = array_reduce($allProductCategories, function(&$r, $x){ $r[$x->slug] = $x->name; return $r;});


    parent::form($instance);
}
```